# What's the best practice to open a fragment on top of an activity

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

I have an activity with a bunch of elements already on it, and I want to open a fragment over the activity.

I want to use a fragment instead of an activity so I can pass a few objects that can't be serializable or parselable.

So far I manage to do this by doing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        .
        .
        .
```

In my activity I just change my `fragment_container` to VISIBLE, and I do a fragment transaction to add the fragment there, while also setting `main_container` that has all the views of my activity to GONE.

I know this is not a very nice solution, I've been thinking of moving all views inside of my `main_container` to a new fragment, so I can replace the container for one or another.

What would be the best practice to open a fragment on top of an activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general rule of thumb that i use:

If you use fragments, then your activities should be extremely dumb.

Meaning that they should not contain any views themselves, and only contain logic to keep track of your fragments (and perhaps logic that only Activities can manage).

I'd take all the views and logic that's currently in your Activity, and move it into a separate Fragment.

Then you could simply replace the "standard" fragment with the new one. 2 fragments, clean and simple.